# Collecting Data points in python when an event occurs

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, finance, moving-average

I want to collect the price points when the price of a stock crossovers the Moving Average (MA). Here I will use Microsoft as an example.

I have the price of the stock as:

```py
Microsoft_Stock = web.DataReader(['MSFT'], 'yahoo', start =..., end=...)
```

and then the moving average of this stock as:

```py
Microsoft_Stock['Moving_Average_20_Days'] = Microsoft_Stock['Close'].rolling(window = 20, min_periods = 1).mean()
```

How can I get a list of the points where these two lines cross?

Comment: The output of your task is unclear. Most crossing points will not be directly on your sampled x dates. Do you want to have the dates before the lines cross, after the lines cross, both, or an interpolation between the date before and after?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a smarter way to extract the price, but you can find the price of the crosspoint by finding the difference between the closing price and the moving average and extracting the absolute value of it, for example, below 1.

```
MSFT['cross_point'] = MSFT['Adj Close'] - MSFT['MA_20_Days']
MSFT[abs(MSFT['cross_point']) < 1]

Attributes  Adj Close   Close   High    Low Open    Volume  MA_20_Days  cross_point
Date                                
2019-01-04  99.652115   101.930000  102.510002  98.930000   99.720001   44060600.0  100.505001  -0.852886
2019-01-08  100.502670  102.800003  103.970001  101.709999  103.040001  31514400.0  101.146667  -0.643997
2019-01-09  101.939812  104.269997  104.879997  103.239998  103.860001  32280800.0  101.592857  0.346954
2019-01-10  101.284798  103.599998  103.750000  102.379997  103.220001  30067600.0  101.843750  -0.558952
2019-01-15  102.663292  105.010002  105.050003  101.879997  102.510002  31587600.0  102.237273  0.426018
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2020-08-14  208.396240  208.899994  209.589996  207.509995  208.759995  17958900.0  208.239999  0.156241
2020-09-28  209.440002  209.440002  212.570007  208.059998  210.880005  32004900.0  209.644500  -0.204498
2020-10-02  206.190002  206.190002  210.990005  205.539993  208.000000  33154800.0  206.369000  -0.178998
2020-10-06  205.910004  205.910004  210.179993  204.820007  208.820007  28554300.0  206.338000  -0.427997
2020-10-27  213.250000  213.250000  214.669998  210.330002  211.589996  36700300.0  214.202501  -0.952501
103 rows × 8 columns
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not specified what exactly your desired output is, I have assumed that you want to have either the date where both values are the same or the date following the crossover point.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt 
import pandas_datareader.data as web

#your input routine
start, end = dt.datetime(2020, 3, 1), dt.datetime(2020, 5, 31)
MS = web.DataReader('MSFT', 'yahoo', start=start, end=end)
MS['MA_20_D'] = MS['Close'].rolling(window = 20, min_periods = 1).mean()

#identify changes between the curves
MS["CP"] = MS["Close"] - MS["MA_20_D"]
MS["CP_Arr"] = MS["CP"].map(np.sign).diff().abs()
#deal with the special case that they have the same value
#either at one point
MS.loc[MS["CP"].shift() == 0, "CP_Arr"] = 0
#or a series of points
MS.loc[MS["CP"] == 0, "CP_Arr"] = 1

#if CP_Arr is now >0, then there was 
#either a crossover between this and the previous date
#or the values are equal at this specific date
#now we filter for this to get an array of all these points
CP_MS = MS[MS["CP_Arr"].ge(1)]
print(CP_MS)

#to verify our approach, let's plot the curves
plt.plot(MS["Close"], label="Close")
plt.plot(MS["MA_20_D"], label="Moving_Average_20_Days")

#and mark the dates we have identified
for covdate in CP_MS.index.values:
    print(covdate)
    plt.axvline(covdate)

plt.xticks(rotation = 45, ha="right")
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]